# TypeError: AngularCompilerPlugin is not a constructor WEBPACK issue

Tags: angular, constructor, typeerror

I am facing webpack issue after my Angular 11-15 upgrade.My upgrade went good. My build is failed.
TypeError: AngularCompilerPlugin is not a constructor.My webpack.prod is failing
need an expert suggestion.

Tried to build my Angular project after angular 15 upgrade and filed.

Comment: you probably have dependencies versions missmatch. please, add your package.json